# opencart order edit page showing 500 error

Tags: json, opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module

Below is the opencart edit order code .

```
public function edit() {
        $this->load->language('sale/order');

        $this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('heading_title'));

        $this->load->model('sale/order');

        unset($this->session->data['cookie']);

        if ($this->validate()) {
            // API
            $this->load->model('user/api');

            $api_info = $this->model_user_api->getApi($this->config->get('config_api_id'));

            if ($api_info) {
                $curl = curl_init();

                // Set SSL if required
                if (substr(HTTPS_CATALOG, 0, 5) == 'https') {
                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PORT, 443);
                }

                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->request->server['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, false);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, HTTPS_CATALOG . 'index.php?route=api/login');
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($api_info));

                $json = curl_exec($curl);

                if (!$json) {
                    $this->error['warning'] = sprintf($this->language->get('error_curl'), curl_error($curl), curl_errno($curl));
                } else {
                    $response = json_decode($json, true);

                    if (isset($response['cookie'])) {
                        $this->session->data['cookie'] = $response['cookie'];
                    }

                    curl_close($curl);
                }
            }
        }

        $this->getForm();
    }
```

if I commented below code . Its showing json exception . But its not showing 500 error . Its showing view part with json exception popup. Continue button is not working . I am using opencart 2x

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->request->server['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, false);
                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, HTTPS_CATALOG . 'index.php?route=api/login');
                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($api_info));

                    $json = curl_exec($curl);
```

Comment: is your code live 
? let us know the url if its live

Comment: Yes . But link is confidential. We cant disclose the link. Its our office rule. Still its in beta version . Once it goes live we can share links . I am using digital occean server .